# SAS: How to select obs with condition

Tags: sas

My data look like this:

```
rep  model   x   Reject
 1    1    1.36    1
 1    2   -0.76    0
 1    3    3.74    1
 1    4   -0.42    0
 2    1   -0.56    0
 2    2   -5.78    0
 2    3   -2.00    0
 2    4   -3.67    0
```

and i want output look like this:

```
rep  model   x   Reject
 1    1     1.36   1
 2    1    -0.56   0
```

I want just 1 from 4 model where Reject=1 but if it can't find,every Obs could be.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please describe the logic for which records you want to select?  Also, please show what code you have tried.

Comment: I have model=1 to 4 and Reject= 0 or 1. rep is a group.
I want just 1 of 4 models.
I look at Reject if Reject=1 (any model) but if all 4 models have Reject= 0 so I can use any model just like random selection or I can use model=1.


About code
I don't know much about SAS code so I use if function but it's error code or the output come out only Reject=1

Answer (score 1):

Sort your data by REP and REJECT and take first record per REP.

```
Proc sort data=have;
   By rep descending reject model;
 Run;

Data select;
   Set have;
     By rep descending reject model;
   If first.rep;
 Run;
```